# Google speed Insights says compression is not enabled even though gzip it is

Tags: performance, compression, gzip, prestashop, pagespeed

I have been trying to improve my website performance, in particular a prestashop website. To measure the speed, I am using googlespeed insights [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcCQg.png) and gmetrix [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLtc9.png), and as we can see in the results, it says that there is no gzip enabled.

[image: gmetrix performance test]

[image: Google speed insights test]

But if you analyze the webpage using Developer Tools from Chrome, you can see that gzip is enabled [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4kMs.png).

[image]

This is the website https://electrogisbert.com, the CCC is enabled and the .haccess for gzip and mod_deflate seem to be ok.

```
 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# Common Fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/font-woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

mod_deflate has been configurated in the server with the deflate.conf file.

What could be the reason of this mismatch?

Kindest Regards

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it with simple words and without any configuration settings suggestions, in order to give you an answer. It is a really complicated situation and it is impossible to guide you through a simple post. It is also hard for me to write it clear and understandable, because English is not my native language. If you want to find more specific answers and solutions, you have to search on the web, using some keywords and ideas from bellow.

> The good part: **Not your fault!**

I assume you are the developer. Everything you have done so far, is right. You don't have to worry any more, because you can't do anything else from your side.

> The bad part: **Server's configuration fault!**

To be fair, i couldn't know the server you are hosting your site. Probably a shared hosting with cPanel. As i said before, nothing you can do, if you are not the SysAdmin of the server. There is a big mess with the configuration of the server, that produces this problem.

---

The story:

> This also happened some months ago and the situation was a pain. I
>   can't explain it with details or with commands and settings, but the
>   general situation (just to give you a quick description) is below:
>
> We had WHM + cloud linux + cPanel + FastCGI. The PHP installations(and
>   versions) are on cloud linux. Nowadays and after a numerous updates
>   from cPanel, the cPanel "arrives" with separated PHP installations
>   itself (and versions). That means that there are double PHP
>   Installations on server, 1 from cloud linux and 1 from cPanel. Each
>   PHP has it's own config and ini files that do not communicate by
>   default.
>
> There are also handlers on the server. With simple words a handler,
>   routes some things from the above. With wrong server side
>   configuration, you can set a handler that does weird things, for
>   example: for PHP 5.4 go use cloud linux PHP(with it's own
>   configuration) but for PHP 5.5 go use cPanel's PHP(with it's own
>   configuration).
>
> In this mess, another part that complicates things, is the binary
>   protocol  you use on the server (cgi, Fastcgi etc.). Some protocols
>   use straight the linux PHP, even if cPanel has it's own. Some others
>   (like FastCGI if i am right) use the cPanel's PHP even if there is PHP
>   installed on linux.
>
> The trick to solve this "bug"(as Sysadmin) is simple. Know what you
>   are doing! If your knowledge is poor and you are not sure what you are
>   doing, you will probably fail. It is really difficult to make all
>   those things work, if you are not the specialist. A wrong setting, can
>   make things fall apart and you won't be able to solve it quickly.

---

Although you (as the developer) enable/disable the PHP settings from cPanel, you could simply edit the wrong ini files, because there is a possibility, the Sysadmin didn't config it right.

**What you can do:**

1. **Are you the developer?** Try to change the PHP Version you use. Maybe you can find yourself lucky and achieve what you want to do. BUT, contact your provider! They are responsible for this.
2. **Are you the Sysadmin?** Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The thing I would say is that I am both. The server is a VPS in Plesk migrated from a CPanel, so I can do some server configuration, do you know something about what could be better?

Comment: You mean specific commands or some general staff? Are you hosting more than 1 site on the VPS?

Comment: I would prefer both, general stuff is useful cause I am hosting more than one site, and specific would be awesome